# Breaking out of SUB-LOOPS with goto

Tags: c#

I have three nested loops. I only want to break out of the last two nested loops (Not all the three nested loops) once a condition has been met at the innermost loop, then continue to the next item at the parent loop.

I do not want to return or set a boolean check. I only want to see if this approach will work. I have a large data, it will take some time to confirm.

```
while (all_Courses.Count != 0)
{
     string drawnCourse = all_Courses[0];
     foreach (Department department in departments)
     {
         if (department.Courses.Contains(drawnCourse))
         {
             foreach (DayOfWeek day in daySlot)
             {
                 if (!department.Courses.Intersect(day.Day).Any())
                 {
                     day.Day[i] = drawnCourse;
                     all_Courses.Remove(drawnCourse);
                     goto NextCourse;
                 }
             }
        }
   }
   NextCourse:
   continue; //start the iteration again at the parent loop

}
```

Comment: `I only want to see if a "goto" will work` Why not try it and post back with any questions you may still have after that.

Comment: Although not a great approach using a "goto", can you please edit your existing post and post the primary basis of the code nested loops, how you are controlling them now and why/where your "goto" should get engaged.

Comment: This sounds like a question you could answer yourself with about 2 minutes effort. I don't see any reason you shouldn't do so. FWIW, I've been writing code for 35+ years and have never used a single `goto`; they make code harder to understand, make it more difficult to follow the flow of execution, and are a nightmare to debug. Most competent programmers think `goto` is evil.

Comment: @DRapp Edited now.

Comment: @Qudus - It would be great to know what this code is trying to do in general because I can tell you that `goto` is going to make your life hard. If you could give us the bigger picture we could give you a better answer.

Comment: @Qudus - It would be great {goto A} [D] a better answer. {end} [C] could give us the bigger picture we could give you {goto D} [B] because I can tell you that `goto` is going to make your life hard. If you {goto C} [A] to know what this code is trying to do in general {goto B}

Comment: Is this a scheduling algorithm?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes

Comment: @Night94: We're not talking asm here. We're talking about higher level languages, where there are many other options. In asm, you don't have any choice. But you knew that already. :-)

Comment: @Qudus - I'd ask about the overall problem if I were you. Provide us with the input data and the required output. This is a difficult problem to get right.

Comment: @Enigmativity Describing the problem can be overwhelming for me. I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Qudus - That's because scheduling is an overwhelmingly large problem. You might find you end up getting little value from this answer unless you try to broaden the scope.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have actually solved the problem. This was just a snippet of the logic which I wanted to see if I could do a different way.

Comment: @Qudus - I'm glad. In any case, the code in your question looks like it is quite inefficient. If that proves to be an issue do feel free to come back and ask a further question.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away with things a bit easier if you use Linq

using System.Linq;

Then, in your loop by department, apply an in-line where clause so it only grabs the one

```
foreach (Department department in 
            departments.Where( d => d.Courses.Contains( drawnCourse)).FirstOrDefault()
            {
               // now you will only get here for the first department that matches
               // and will exit out after that.  If no day match, it wont even try 
               // another department.

            }
```

The ( d => …. ) portion is implied as

while I am within the parenthesis of the WHERE clause, have the variable "d" represent whatever the current department is within the list.  Now I can compare that, and as soon as I get to the FIRST(or default) record, allow to continue.

There should only be one department that a course would probably be associated with and would exit right after that and not even try a second department.

As for your outer loop of the "allCourses", you probably need to iterate through via the index, starting at position 0.  If you remove courses from the list, it will obviously be reduced.  But now, if you remove the course you are on, you don't want to increase the count because your new "X" record is now what was in the X+1 index.  Careful on how you think you are processing them.

Answer (score 0):

Goto is not a good option at all. For Multiple inner loop break you have to set a condition to exit/break from loop.

```
        while (all_Courses.Count != 0)
        {
            string drawnCourse = all_Courses[0];
            foreach (Department department in departments)
            {
                foreach (DayOfWeek day in daySlot)
                {
                    if (condition)
                    {
                        all_Courses.Remove(drawnCourse);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!all_Courses.Contains(drawnCourse))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```